# Apache Kafka with multiple partitions distributed deployment

Tags: spring, spring-boot, apache-kafka, kafka-consumer-api, spring-kafka

I have a kafka topic with 10 partitions. I plan to deploy two application on different servers. One application will read from partitions 0 to 4. While the other will read from partitions 5 to 9.
**Deployment 1**

```
@KafkaListener(topicPartitions =
        { @TopicPartition(topic = "testpartition", partitions = { "0", "1","2", "3","4" })
              
              })
    public void receive(ConsumerRecord record) {
        System.out.println(String.format("Listener 1 -Topic - %s, Partition - %d, Value: %s", kafkaTopic, record.partition(), record.value()));
    }
```

**Deployment 2**

```
@KafkaListener(topicPartitions =
        { @TopicPartition(topic = "testpartition", partitions = { "5", "6","7", "8","9" })
              
              })
    public void receive(ConsumerRecord record) {
        System.out.println(String.format("Listener 2 -Topic - %s, Partition - %d, Value: %s", kafkaTopic, record.partition(), record.value()));
    }
```

So we will be having two consumer groups as application is deployed separately on different servers. 
As each application is consuming from different partitions
will this lead to unwanted replication of messages on kafka topic?
Will all the messages get replicated twice. Also if this is the case then will there be message duplication?
Is this the right way to deploy the consumer application in distributed environment or there a better way?

Answer (score 0):

Since you are manually assigning the partitions, no, there will be no duplication and each instance will only receive records from its assigned partitions.

When you say "replicated"; that depends on the replication factor when the topic is created. Replicas are used to ensure there are multiple copies on different broker instances in order to handle server failures. Replication is not the same as duplication.

But even though records are replicated in that way, there is only one logical instance of each record.

It **is** possible to get duplicate records in certain (rare) failure scenarios, unless you enable exactly once semantics.

The other way to deploy it is to use Kafka Group Management and let Kafka distribute the partitions across the instances, either using its default algorithm or using a custom `ConsumerPartitionAssignor`.

Comment: Thanks for the input gary. Can Kafka group management be applied if listeners are in seperate deployments. I know that if there is a single project then all consumers have same group I'd and so Kafka distributes it among them. But this is not the case of distributed deployments

Comment: They must be in the same group. There is no reason you can’t do that with multiple deployments.